# Count the number of times the Program has been launched

Tags: c#

How can I get the number of times a program has previously run in c# without keeping a file and tallying. Is there a Application class or something in c# to check the count.
Please give a detailed explantion as i know nothing about it.This is A windows console application not windows forms.

Comment: What kind of app it is ? winforms ? wpf ?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to save the count without storing it on some form of disk storage

Answer (score 3):

You can do that my creating an Entry in the `Registry`. And another way is by using an `Application Settings`.

But I prefer `Application Settings` because it has less task to do. 
[See HERE: Creating an Application Settings.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) 
[Tutorial From Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9WIvYQ1dNU)

Comment: The application settings will still be stored in a file on disk somewhere, so technically that violates the OPs requirements, even though the code need not explicitly mention or touch the file.

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of Windows automatically maintain this information in the registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\UserAssist`.

The data is obfuscated with [ROT13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13), but that's easy to "decrypt". A [free utility](http://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/userassist/) (with source code) is available and can serve as your starting point.

Answer (score 2):

1. You could send a message to a database or webservice every time the program starts up (assuming there's a network connection).
2. You could keep a count on some form of hardware thet's not a standard storage device (therefore not technically being a file).
3. You could make a registry entry that you keep the count in (if you ignore the fact that the registry entry is, at some level, persisted into a file somewhere).
4. You could just have a file somewhere that keeps track of the count.  Not sure why you're so opposed to this one in the first place....

Comment: +1 since you actually give solutions which meet the OP's requirement of "without keeping a file and tallying".

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a Winforms application, the you can easily use the Application Settings.  Right click on your Solution Name --> Properties --> Settings Tab.  [More info and tutorial here.](http://www.dotnetperls.com/settings)

Then, every time your program starts, increment this setting and save it.

Answer (score 0):

Ref: [Count the number of times the Program has been launched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527756/count-the-number-of-times-the-program-has-been-launched)

In my knowledge Windows does not keep this information for you. You would have to tally the value somewhere (file, database, registry setting).

**Better way is [Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh%28VS.90%29.aspx) as:**

[Create setting in app.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and then use it as:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.FirstUserSetting = "abc";
```

then, you usually do this in the Closing event handler of the main form. The following statement to Save settings method.

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

**Implementation using Registry:**

```
static string AppRegyPath = "Software\\Cheeso\\ApplicationName";
static string rvn_Runs = "Runs";

private Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey _appCuKey;
public Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey AppCuKey
{
    get
    {
        if (_appCuKey == null)
        {
            _appCuKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(AppRegyPath, true);
            if (_appCuKey == null)
                _appCuKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(AppRegyPath);
        }
        return _appCuKey;
    }
    set { _appCuKey = null; }
}

public int UpdateRunCount()
{
    int x = (Int32)AppCuKey.GetValue(rvn_Runs, 0);
    x++;
    AppCuKey.SetValue(rvn_Runs, x);
    return x;
}
```

If it's a WinForms app, you can hook the Form's OnClosing event to run UpdateCount.

Then Check tutorial to [Read, write and delete from registry with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3389/Read-write-and-delete-from-registry-with-C)